# Using Ternary Operator to change an input attribute

Tags: php, html, input, attributes, ternary-operator

The idea is that I have a bunch of inputs in a form and when I send it (to the same page) I want to keep the selected options values.

This what is how I managed to make it work.

```
<input type="number"  
    <?= isset($_POST['price']) ? 'value="' . $_POST['price'] . '"' : '' ?> 
>
```

The result if "price" has been set previously is that the input will the attribute

value="123"

Is it possible to write the same without concatenation?

I tried but **"**, **'** , and **$_POST** seem to be getting in each other way so I just get php error or just write plain text on the page.

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the null coalescing operator and output your inputted data in the value attribute:

```
<input type="number" value="<?= $_POST['price'] ?? '' ?>">
```

But it will not escape user input, so you wouldn't want that.

Instead:

```
<input type="number" value="<?= htmlentities($_POST['price'] ?? '') ?>">
```

Or:

```
<input type="number" value=
"<?= isset($_POST['price']) ? htmlentities($_POST['price']) : '' ?>"
>
```

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: Thank, that is much better. I haven't really looked into that kind of vulnerabilities, could you recommend some resources please?